# Scala: avoid type erasure

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, instanceof

From the following code:

```
type Structure = Map[String, Any]

def getStructureSourceNames(structuresDesc: Structure): Iterable[String] = {
  val subColsDesc: Map[String, String] =
    structuresDesc.filter(_._2.isInstanceOf[String]).asInstanceOf[Map[String, String]]
  val subStructuresDesc: Map[String, Structure] = structuresDesc
    .filter(_._2.isInstanceOf[Map[String, Structure]])
    .asInstanceOf[Map[String, Structure]]

  subColsDesc.values ++ subStructuresDesc.values.flatMap(getStructureSourceNames(_))
}
```

I want to pass a recursive Map of (String -> String), ia. an example of Structure is:

```
Map("test" -> Map(
        "newid" -> "id",
        "newstring" -> "string",
        "toto" -> Map("newdouble" -> "double")
      ),
      "otherid" -> "id")
```

The method `getStructureSourceNames` should return the list of "final" value, ia. browse the whole tree and for each leaft, get the String value.

When I run this code, this drives me to:

```
Warning:(78, 32) non-variable type argument String in type scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Structure] (the underlying of Map[String,Structure]) is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
  .filter(_._2.isInstanceOf[Map[String, Structure]])
```

Moreover, I don't like to use isInstanceOf / asInstanceOf. By googling, I found that I could use pattern matching to check for the type, and get the Map with expected typing, but I can"t find how to do it.

Would you have an example of such code?

Comment: Thus, your values are either a **String** or another **Map** with **String** keys and where the values are either **String** or another **Map**... - Is that right? Also, do you have control over the creation fo the map? Like if I propose a solution that requires the **Map** to be of different type, is that feasible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 kinds of pattern matching:

1) pattern matching on a `sealed trait` (good)

2) pattern matching where patterns involve matching with arbitrary classes  and equality checks (not better than `instanceOf` checks)

To avoid `2)` you need to make the type you want to match a sealed trait:

```
sealed trait ConfigValue
case class StringValue(v: String) extends ConfigValue
case class MapValue(map: Map[String, ConfigValue]) extends ConfigValue

val struct: ConfigValue = MapValue(Map("key1" -> StringValue("v1"),
                   "key2" -> MapValue(Map("sub" -> StringValue("val")))))

def allValues(s: ConfigValue): Iterable[String] = {
  s match {
    case StringValue(v) => Seq(v)
    case MapValue(map) => map.values.flatMap(v => allValues(v))
  }
}

println(allValues(struct))
```

By the way your structure looks similar to json. Maybe you could reuse some json library.

Comment: Awesome thanks, I was looking for it but couldn't make it work

Comment: To make it even better, I switch StringValue and MapValue to implicit class, so I can declare only val struct = Map("key1" -> "v1",
                   "key2" -> Map("sub" -> "val"))

Comment: Happy to help. Although be careful, it's easy to create a mess with implicits. Especially implicit classes are considered harmful nowdays. I'd personally would rather get away with just creating factory methods like `ConfigValue.fromMap`